# How do I change information shown on Windows 8 lock screen?

Tags: windows-8

I have some info on my lock screen by default.. is there a way to add / change it? is there special kind of apps - which can be displayed on the lock screen? some hackery trickery perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows Store applications need to be specifically coded to have notifications appear on the start screen.  You have the ability to select up to seven applications for small notifications (typically an icon and a number for new messages) and one application for large notifications (a portion of text from your latest email, for example).

To select the applications which show on the lock screen, head to the **Personalize** section in the "Change PC Settings" area, select *Lock screen* at the top, and select the applications to display.

[image: Windows 8 Personalize Lock Screen]

Comment: brilliant, thanks a lot! do you know by any chance - where can I read about - specifically coded app part ? I really want to make a small app for myself to display a bit of info on the lock screen.. if you have a link handy - i'd appreciate very much

Comment: @Bobb: You can get started via the MSDN link in my answer [here](http://superuser.com/a/493615/138343).